# how to pass two result in same view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am new with codeigniter.I have written controller,model.view.

I want to execute the another query in the model which having the "ID" from first model query in the where condition and pass the seperate results for both the both query in same view.

i have explain it in model and view.
how can i do this.need some syntax how can i do this.
or is this correct way or do somwthing??

**Controller**

```
class demo extends CI_Controller
{
    function getRecords()
    {
        $offset = trim($this->input->get('off'));
        $this->load->model('demo_model');
        $data = $this->demo_model->get_messages($offset);
        $return = $this->load->view('demo_view',array('records'=>$data),true);
        die($return);
    }   
}
```

**Model**

```
class demo_model extends CI_Model
{
    function get_messages($offset = 0)
    {
        $q = $this->db->query(" select Id,cloum2 from table");

        //  want to use ID from above query in to second query

        //  Like sql="select * from table where id='$id'" ; 

        //  and how i pass the separate result for both query inthe view

    return $q->result_array();
     }

}
```

**View** demo_view;

```
<?php foreach($records as $row) :?>
 <div> do something with $row </div>

 <div> //want use second query foreach here  </div>
<?php endforeach ;?>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run a second query for each of the messages returned from the first query and pass the result to view?

Comment: @harmeetKAur:yes,but not want combine results for both query pass separate result on view(look at demo_view).

Comment: @Swap - your problem can be solved in one query, but you need to give more details like: are those separate tables. or the same table. and they just share the same id in relation?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan:these are separate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both queries will return PHP arrays so you can do something like.

MODEL

```
function get_messages($offset = 0)
{
    $q = $this->db->query(" select Id,cloum2 from table");
   return $q->result_array();
 }

 function get_id($id){
    $q = $this->db->query("select * from table where id='$id'");
   return $q->result_array();
  }
```

CONTROLLER

```
  class demo extends CI_Controller{
      function getRecords(){
            $offset = trim($this->input->get('off'));
           $this->load->model('demo_model');
           $data = $this->demo_model->get_messages($offset);
           for($c=0;$c<count($data);$c++){
              $data[$c]['innerRow']=$this->demo_model->get_id($data[$c]['id']);
           }
           $return = $this->load->view('demo_view',array('records'=>$data),true);
           die($return);
     }
```

VIEW

```
     <?php foreach($records as $row) :?>
          <div> do something with $row </div>
         <div>  
             <?php foreach($row['innerRow'] as $innerrow) :?>
              ......
             <?php endforeach ;?>
         </div>

     <?php endforeach ;?>
```

(But this isn't such a good idea as you will run a bunch of queries to the model. Its better to think of a nicer query)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRecords()
    {
        $offset = trim($this->input->get('off'));
        $this->load->model('demo_model');
        $data = $this->demo_model->get_messages($offset);

        $secresult=array();
        foreach($data as $msg)
        {
          $res = $this->demo_model->get_result($msg['id']); // pass id to query 
          $secresult[]=$res;
        }

        $return = $this->load->view('demo_view',array('records'=>$data,     'theresult'=>$secresult),true);
        die($return);
    }
```

In your view file, you can use `theresult` for the second loop.